# matplotlib correct colors/colorbar for plot with multiple surfaces each of a different color

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Is it possible to plot multiple surfaces in one pyplot figure? Here is my attempt. The `ax.plot_surface` command seems to reset the figure, as I only get a single plane in the resulting plot. I am hoping to produce "stacked" planes, each with distinctive colors, and a color bar showing the numeric value of each color. Currently my colors show up wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pylab
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

dat = open('ex.csv', 'w')
dat.write('x,y,z,c\n')
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(20):
         for c in range(0,7):
             dat.write(','.join([str(s) for s in [x,y,x+y+c,c/10.0,'\n']]))
dat.close()

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
dat = np.genfromtxt('ex.csv', delimiter=',',skip_header=1)
X_dat = dat[:,0]
Y_dat = dat[:,1]
Z_dat = dat[:,2]
C_dat = dat[:,3]
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for color in np.unique(C_dat):
    X, Y, Z, C = np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])
    for i in range(len(X_dat)):
        if C_dat[i]==color:
            X = np.append(X,X_dat[i])
            Y = np.append(Y,Y_dat[i])
            Z = np.append(Z,Z_dat[i])
            C = np.append(C,C_dat[i])

    xi = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),100)
    yi = np.linspace(Y.min(),Y.max(),100)

    zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
    ci = griddata((X, Y), C, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

    xig, yig = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
    surf = ax1.plot_surface(xig, yig, zi,facecolors=cm.rainbow(ci), alpha = 0.7)

xi = np.linspace(X_dat.min(),X_dat.max(),100)
yi = np.linspace(Y_dat.min(),Y_dat.max(),100)
ci = griddata((X_dat, Y_dat), C_dat, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.rainbow)
m.set_array(ci)
col = plt.colorbar(m)
plt.show()
```

[image]
(there should be a red plane)

Comment: Editing your question like this invalidates the answer(s) already given. Next time it would be better to just ask a new question.

Comment: @tom I really thought the code I posted was a MCVE

Comment: @tom But I generate the file in the code

Comment: ah, I apologise, I didn't read it closely enough

Comment: @kilojoules, I've just edited my answer to address your new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the line

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

outside of the `for color in...` loop. By recreating the axes each iteration, you hide the previously created surfaces

---

**EDIT** (to answer second question about colormaps)

You need to [normalise](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html) your data. Currently, you have facecolors in the range 0 to 0.6, so when you feed the maximum (0.6) to `cm.rainbow`, you get green, not red (since it expects a range of 0 to 1).

Here's a modified script, which I think works as it should. We use [`Normalise`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) from `matplotlib.colors` with a `vmin` and `vmax` determined from your `C_dat` data. Then, use `facecolors=cm.rainbow(norm(ci))` to set the colors of your surfaces.

You also then want to set the array of your ScalarMappable using the values in `C_dat`, so we don't need to use `griddata` again here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pylab
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

dat = open('ex.csv', 'w')
dat.write('x,y,z,c\n')
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(20):
         for c in range(0,7):
             dat.write(','.join([str(s) for s in [x,y,x+y+c,c/10.0,'\n']]))
dat.close()

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
dat = np.genfromtxt('ex.csv', delimiter=',',skip_header=1)
X_dat = dat[:,0]
Y_dat = dat[:,1]
Z_dat = dat[:,2]
C_dat = dat[:,3]

# Create a Normalize instance.
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=C_dat.min(),vmax=C_dat.max())

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for color in np.unique(C_dat):
    X, Y, Z, C = np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])
    for i in range(len(X_dat)):
        if C_dat[i]==color:
            X = np.append(X,X_dat[i])
            Y = np.append(Y,Y_dat[i])
            Z = np.append(Z,Z_dat[i])
            C = np.append(C,C_dat[i])

    xi = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),100)
    yi = np.linspace(Y.min(),Y.max(),100)

    zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
    ci = griddata((X, Y), C, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

    xig, yig = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

    # Note the use of norm in the facecolors option
    surf = ax1.plot_surface(xig, yig, zi,facecolors=cm.rainbow(norm(ci)), alpha = 0.7)

m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.rainbow)
m.set_array(np.unique(C_dat))

col = plt.colorbar(m)

plt.show()
```

[image]